# multiple return types in optional function

Tags: objective-c, swift3, option-type

```
@objc protocol OptionalProtocol: class { // below error during this type

  @objc optional func run5() -> (String?, Int?)
}
```

> error: Method cannot be marked @objc because its result type cannot be represented in Objective-C

```
@objc protocol OptionalProtocol: class { // no error

  @objc optional func run5() -> (String?)
}
```

I am creating an optional function with multiple return types but a single return type is working fine but when I return more than one value it gives above error.
how to fix it.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Objective-C doesn't know tuplets.

The second example doesn't return a tuple, `(String?)` is practically the same as `String?`.

If you need to return multiple objects to Objective-C wrap the objects in an array, a dictionary or a custom class.